# How do I loop through a JSON array with React Native?

Tags: php, json, reactjs, react-native

I've recently started on a React Native project and have been struggling with mapping JSON objects A LOT.  I've looked through a lot of posts but have received the same error each time.

Below is a few snippets of the code I'm working with on mapping the JSON

```
  getUserNotifications = () => {
    var uname = this.state.userName;
    fetch('https://examp.le/endpoint?getNotifications&username=' + uname) // api url
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({notifications: responseJson});
          console.log("Notification response:" + this.state.notifications);
        //   alert(responseJson);
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
  }
```

Which returns something like the JSON snippet below

```
[
   {
      "data":{
         "from":"user",
         "time":"13 hours ago",
         "fromPfp":"users/287/avatar/application_1588872189.jpg",
         "type":"commentLike"
      }
   },
   {
      "data":{
         "from":"user",
         "time":"13 hours ago",
         "fromPfp":"users/287/avatar/application_1588872189.jpg",
         "type":"comment_mention"
      }
   }
]
```

Here's my mapping code

```
        {this.state.notifications.data.map(data => (
                <View style= {{ display: "flex", flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", backgroundColor: "#2a2a2a", padding: 15 }}>
                    <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 12, display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 6, marginLeft: 8 }}>{data.from} liked your post</Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={{ color: "#ddd", fontSize: 9, display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", marginLeft: 18, marginBottom: 20 }}>{data.time}</Text>
            </View>  
        ))}
```

I keep receiving `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.notifications.data.map')` as my error.

**-- snippets --**

Notification response in getUserNotifications displays this in console:

```
Notification response:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

JSON.stringify in render:

```
json after the render is finished: [
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"2 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"2 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"20 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/287/avatar/application_1588872189.jpg",
      "type":"commentLike"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"20 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/287/avatar/application_1588872189.jpg",
      "type":"commentLike"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"20 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/287/avatar/application_1588872189.jpg",
      "type":"comment_mention"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"20 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/291/avatar/application_1593241576.jpg",
      "type":"comment_mention"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"21 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/271/avatar/application_1592193853.jpg",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"21 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/271/avatar/application_1592193853.jpg",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"21 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/271/avatar/application_1592193853.jpg",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"21 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/271/avatar/application_1592193853.jpg",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"21 hours ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/271/avatar/application_1592193853.jpg",
      "type":"post"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"1 day ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/291/avatar/application_1593241576.jpg",
      "type":"comment_mention"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"1 day ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"comment_mention"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"1 day ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"1 day ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"2 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"post"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"2 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"2 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/287/avatar/application_1588872189.jpg",
      "type":"comment_mention"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"2 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/287/avatar/application_1588872189.jpg",
      "type":"commentLike"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"3 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"4 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/287/avatar/application_1588872189.jpg",
      "type":"like"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"4 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"post"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"5 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"post"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"6 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"post"
   },
   {
      "from":"user",
      "time":"6 days ago",
      "fromPfp":"users/270/avatar/application_1588987915.png",
      "type":"post"
   }
]
```

Errors

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See LINK for more information.%s, 

Check the render method of `NotifsScreen`., , 
    in Unknown (at NotifsScreen.js:201)
```

The following error repeats itself 25 times:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Check your code at NotifsScreen.js:201.
```

Line 201 is the first

---

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ActivityIndicator, Image, ScrollView, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, RefreshControl, Fragment } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents, useTheme } from 'react-navigation';
import { gStyle, colors } from '../constants';

// import { userInfo } from './HomeScreen';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'



class NotifsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      bio: '',
      followers: '',
      following: '',
      postcount: '',
      avatar: '',
      verified: '',
      response: '',
      notifications: ''
    };
  }

  
  getUserNotifications = () => {
    var uname = this.state.userName;
    var uname = uname.replace(/\"/g, "")
    fetch('https://examp.le/endpoint?getNotifications&username=' + uname) // api url
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
          let newArr = [];

          for (const item of responseJson) {
            newArr.push(item.data);
          }
          this.setState({notifications: newArr});
          console.log("Notification response: " + this.state.notifications);
        //   alert(responseJson);
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
  }

  // async component did mount (basically the same as document did load)
  async componentDidMount() {  
      console.log("Component mounted on notifications");
    
    try{
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userName");
      let firstname = await AsyncStorage.getItem("firstName");
      let lastname = await AsyncStorage.getItem("lastName");
      let bio = await AsyncStorage.getItem("bio");
      let followers = await AsyncStorage.getItem("followerCount");
      let following = await AsyncStorage.getItem("followingCount");
      let postcount = await AsyncStorage.getItem("postCount");
      let avatar = await AsyncStorage.getItem("avatar");
      let verified = await AsyncStorage.getItem("verified");
      if(verified !== undefined) { 
        this.setState({ userName: value, avatar: avatar, firstName: firstname, lastName: lastname, followers: followers, following: following, postcount: postcount, verified: verified, bio: bio }, function () {   });
      } else {
        this.setState({ userName: value, avatar: avatar, firstName: firstname, lastName: lastname, followers: followers, following: following, postcount: postcount, verified: "no", bio: bio }, function () {   });
      }
      console.log("USER SET: " + value + " ON NOTIFICATIONS");
      console.log("Attempting to get notifications...");
      this.getUserNotifications();
      // return value.json();
    }
  catch(e){
      console.log('caught error', e);
      // Handle exceptions
  }
  }

  refreshGetUserInfo = () =>{
    // Simple GET request using fetch
    var username = this.state.userName;
    var username = username.replace(/\"/g, "")
    fetch('https://examp.le/endpoint?username=' + username) // api url
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("userName", responseJson.userName)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("firstName",responseJson.firstName)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("lastName", responseJson.lastName)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("bio", responseJson.bio)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("postCount", responseJson.postCount)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("followerCount", responseJson.followerCount)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("followingCount", responseJson.followingCount)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("verified", responseJson.verified)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("moderator", responseJson.moderator)
        AsyncStorage.setItem("avatar", responseJson.avatar)
        
        console.log("[L1] Successfully got information from profile page.");

          // the code below is a working json example
  
          // now i'm going to add the array to async storage so that i will be able to access this data
          // from other screens.


          let value = AsyncStorage.getItem("userName");
          let firstname = AsyncStorage.getItem("firstName");
          let lastname = AsyncStorage.getItem("lastName");
          let bio = AsyncStorage.getItem("bio");
          let followers = AsyncStorage.getItem("followerCount");
          let following = AsyncStorage.getItem("followingCount");
          let postcount = AsyncStorage.getItem("postCount");
          let avatar = AsyncStorage.getItem("avatar");
          let verified = AsyncStorage.getItem("verified");
          if(verified !== undefined) { 
            this.setState({ userName: value, avatar: avatar, firstName: firstname, lastName: lastname, followers: followers, following: following, postcount: postcount, verified: verified, bio: bio }, function () {   });
          } else {
            this.setState({ userName: value, avatar: avatar, firstName: firstname, lastName: lastname, followers: followers, following: following, postcount: postcount, verified: "no", bio: bio }, function () {   });
          }
          console.log("USER SET: " + value + " ON NOTIFICATIONS");
          // return value.json();
          var uname = this.state.userName;
          var uname = uname.replace(/\"/g, "")
            this.props.navigation.setParams({
              Title: uname,
              Badge: this.state.verified
          });
          this.setState({refreshing: false}); 


        })
  }

  onRefresh() {
    // get latest data
    // this.refreshGetUserInfo();
    this.setState({refreshing: false}); 
  }


  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerTitleStyle: gStyle.headerTitleStyle,
          headerTitle: (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <Text style={{ color: "#ffffff", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold', marginRight: 5 }}>Notifications</Text>                
            </View>
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colors.darkColor,
            color: colors.white20,
            borderBottomColor: colors.darkColor,
          }
        };

  };


  render() {
    const user = this.state.userName;
    const avatar = "https://examp.le/" + this.state.avatar;
    var fixedAvatar = avatar.replace(/\"/g, "");
    var fname = this.state.firstName;
    var fname = fname.toString().replace(/\"/g, "")
    var lname = this.state.lastName;
    var lname = lname.toString().replace(/\"/g, "")
    var uname = this.state.userName;
    var uname = uname.toString().replace(/\"/g, "")
    var bio = this.state.bio;
    var bio = bio.toString().replace(/\"/g, "")
    var json = JSON.stringify(this.state.notifications);
    console.log("json after the render is finished: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.notifications));
    if (!this.state.notifications) {
      return <View                  
      contentContainerStyle={gStyle.contentContainer}
      style={gStyle.container.dark}
      /> 
   }
  return (
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={gStyle.contentContainer}
      style={gStyle.container.dark}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)} />
      }>
      {/* <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.notifications)}</Text> */}

      {
  this.state.notifications.map((data) => (
    <Fragment>
      <View
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "row",
          backgroundColor: "#2a2a2a",
          padding: 15,
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#fff",
            fontSize: 12,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            marginTop: 6,
            marginLeft: 8,
          }}
        >
          {data.from} liked your post
        </Text>

        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#ddd",
            fontSize: 9,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            marginLeft: 18,
            marginBottom: 20,
          }}
        >
          {data.time}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </Fragment>
  ))
}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
}



export default NotifsScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
..... 


{
  this.state.notifications.map((data) => (
    <Fragment>
      <View
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "row",
          backgroundColor: "#2a2a2a",
          padding: 15,
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#fff",
            fontSize: 12,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            marginTop: 6,
            marginLeft: 8,
          }}
        >
          {stuff.from} liked your post
        </Text>

        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#ddd",
            fontSize: 9,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            marginLeft: 18,
            marginBottom: 20,
          }}
        >
          {stuff.time}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </Fragment>
  ));
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when running this code:
`Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.`

Comment: Did the type error get resolved at least ? im not sure why you are getting that error because {stuff.from} and {stuff.time} are wrapped in Text components. Can you console.log where that error is coming from.

Comment: Still getting the same error as before.  I tried adding this solution with the other solution and it's not throwing any errors, but it's not returning the JSON information.

Comment: If you can restructure the json like above it will work, i will be back in a few to provide a solution to re arrange the data if changing the json is not possible for you. Give me a couple of hours.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't even see that you wanted the restructure. I restructured it and I'm still not getting any return.

Comment: @Channing have you tried rebuilding it ? and restarting the emulator ? it should work

Comment: also, share how `getUserNotifications` is getting called

Comment: getUserNotifications gets called in my componentDidMount. Just implemented the code that you posted that rebuilds the JSON into the format, with the JSON stringify after render being how you wanted it to be rebuilt. I'm still not getting any response from the JSON map, though.

Comment: It shows [object Object] for the responseJson console.log. I updated my question with snippets of what console is outputting.

Comment: i updated the code, try it again. being that you restructured your json, this should work.

Comment: Updated the code with your code. I'm getting two errors, added them to my original question.

Comment: can you share your whole component

Comment: I'm not sure if you need all of it, please tell me if you do, but I just added the return part of my code.

Comment: added the whole thing, check original

Comment: just got back let me check

Comment: Can you import `Fragment` from react, not react native. Honestly you don't really need it, if you are using view. But its up to you.

Comment: That did it! Imported Fragment with React and it solved the issue. Thank you so much BARNOWL!

Comment: No worries :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

As the error information points out, initially the this.state.notification is undefined. You have to take into account that **fetch** is an **[async call](https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp)** so probably during the first render, this.state.notification is not filled with any information. You can test this adding a console.log before returning the mapping code you have written.

To make sure you only access the notifications object inside this.state when it is already filled with the API call information, you could do something like this:

```
if (!this.state.notifications) {
   return <View/> 
}

return (
   <EnterYourCodeHere/>
)
```

This way, you return an empty View if there is no notifications coming from the API call. But when the information is received, you can map the json coming from it with your existing code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response and explaination on this! I added `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.notifications));` in the render and it does log all of the JSON.  I went ahead and tried your code and I am not getting that error anymore, it's just not returning any of the code in the mapping.